# WCF Service - Getting list from request header

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, http-headers

I'm trying to recover a list key-value from request header in a WCF service. I'm able to recover a single property, but I can't find how to recover a list.

This is my call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <tem:header1>Header 1</tem:header1>
    <tem:Properties>
      <tem:property>
        <key>KEY.ONE</key>
        <value>value1</value>
      </tem:property>
      <tem:property>
        <key>KEY.TWO</key>
        <value>value2</value>
      </tem:property>
    </tem:Properties>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:function1>
      <tem:param1>100</tem:param1>
    </tem:function1>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is how I recover "header1":

```
MessageHeaders headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
string header1 = headers.GetHeader<string>("header1", "http://tempuri.org/");
```

I thought that I could use something like:

```
IDictionary<string, string> properties = headers.GetHeader<Dictionary<string, string>>("Properties", "http://tempuri.org/");
```

But *properties* is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSDN says the `GetHeader<T>(string, string)` method only is capable of returning header that is serialized by `DataContractSerializer`, which means your `property` objects should exist as a .NET type.

What you can do instead is to use `GetHeader<T>(string, string, XmlObjectSerializer)` which uses serializer to deserialize the content of the header value and return it.

For that you need to implement your own serializer that will read the content and return dictionary. I think something like that would work (depends on whether `key` and `value` are strictly in this order or can be swapped). Also, I didn't check what happens with namespaces.

```
public class MySerializer : XmlObjectSerializer
{

  public override object ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, bool verifyObjectName)
  {
    reader.ReadFullStartElement();
    Dictionary<string, string> r = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while (reader.IsStartElement("property"))
    {
      reader.ReadFullStartElement("property");
      reader.ReadFullStartElement("key");
      string key = reader.ReadContentAsString();
      reader.ReadEndElement();
      reader.ReadFullStartElement("value");
      string value = reader.ReadContentAsString();
      reader.ReadEndElement();
      r.Add(key, value);

      reader.ReadEndElement();
      reader.MoveToContent();
    }
    return r;
  }

  public override void WriteStartObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void WriteObjectContent(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void WriteEndObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override bool IsStartObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm new in **WCF**, can you give me an example of use? I've read I have to implement de **XmlObjectSerializer**, but I'm not quiet sure how to implement this to use it as a Dictionary.